# Как пробросить ключ и пароль к ssh в npm install?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, npm

Если я клонирую 
репозиторий командой 
git clone ssh://git@repo.typn.com:87955/react-svg-project.git

```
То у меня выводится ошибка 
Клонирование в «react-svg-project»…
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
git@repo.typn.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.

Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа
и репозиторий существует.
```

Но выполнив команду

```
ssh-add
```

И введя пароль для ssh ключа.

Клонирование выполняется успешно.
git clone ssh://git@repo.typn.com:87955/react-svg-project.git

Но если поместить в файле package.json зависимость

"react-svg-project": "git+ssh://git@repo.typn.com:87955/react-svg-project.git"

И выполнить 
sudo npm install, то появляется ошибка

```
➜  svo git:(develop) sudo npm install                                        
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (ssh://git@repo.typn.com:87955/react-svg-project.git) git@repo.typn.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (ssh://git@repo.typn.com:87955/react-svg-project.git) fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (ssh://git@repo.typn.com:87955/react-svg-project.git) 
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (ssh://git@repo.typn.com:87955/react-svg-project.git) Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (ssh://git@repo.typn.com:87955/react-svg-project.git) и репозиторий существует.
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@1.0.3: bcrypt < v2.0.0 is susceptible to bcrypt wrap-around bug. Upgrade to bcrypt >= v2.0.0 for improved support for newer bcrypt hashes
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code 128
```

Вот как в таком случае указать ключ и пароль для ssh когда выполняется npm install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

программа *ssh* взаимодействеут с программой *ssh-agent* через *socket-файл*, адрес которого эта программа (*ssh-agent*) передаёт через переменную окружения `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`.

раз вам надо передать доступ к вашему экземпляру *ssh-agent* при выполнении программы *git* (которая вызывается программой *npm*) от имени другого пользователя, то и передайте ей текущее значение упомянутой переменной окружения с помощью параметра программы *sudo*:

```
sudo SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK npm install
```

обычно данный *socket-файл* доступен только владельцу, но раз в качестве «другого пользователя» выступает пользователь с идентификатором 0 (обычно с именем «root»), то по этому поводу можно не беспокоиться: он сможет и прочитать из, и записать в данный *socket-файл*.

---

среди альтернативных путей передачи этой переменной окружения можно отметить (а) добавление имени переменной в переменную `env_keep` в файле `/etc/sudoers` (или в каком-нибудь из `/etc/sudoers.d/*`) — для всех:

```
Defaults env_keep += SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

или только для указанного пользователя(-ей):

```
Defaults:пользователь env_keep += SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

и (б) использование опции `-E` программы *sudo*. в этом случае будут переданы **все** переменные окружения, что может быть нежелательным.

---

p.s. а парольную фразу, которой зашифрован ваш секретный ключ, «пробрасывать» некуда и незачем: вы вручаете её программе *ssh-agent* (выполняя `ssh-add`), она расшифровывает ключ и хранит его в памяти указанный промежуток времени (или пока работает, если промежуток не задан ни в конф. файле, ни с помощью опции `-t промежуток` программы *ssh-add*).

Comment: У меня пишет  после команды 
Defaults env_keep += SSH_AUTH_SOCK



Command 'Defaults' not found, did you mean:

  command 'defaults' from deb gnustep-base-runtime

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

Comment: это директива в упомянутом конфигурационном файле, который надо редактировать программой *visudo*.